How can my add-on extension access its own manifest
In Blender versions prior to 4.2 I was able to access the version of my add-on in the register function through bl_info.
In Blender 4.2 this is no longer available as the bl_info variable gets deleted by addon_utils.py.
The information about the add-on is now stored in blender_manifest.toml. How can my add-on access this information?
(PS. I could parse the toml myself, but i am hoping the api provides a way to access the info)
